# How to enable javascript in browser if it was disable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want know javascript is disabled by browser if yes than how can i enabled.

Comment: Search before posting, please. That's not only the rule on SO, it's been the rule on every other Q&A site, every support forum, every BBS, for pushing 30 years.

Answer (score 1):

for enabling javascript

refer http://enable-javascript.com/

or to check

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.location.href = 'page-with-javascript.html';
</script>
```

if the user has javascript enabled, they'll immediately be taken to the javascript friendly version.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<noscript>` tag to set your server side validation.

refer : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript